# Is it necessary to make ablution before saying Adhan(call to prayer)?

Tags: adhan, taharah

How clean should a Muslim be before making an Adhan(call to prayer)?

Is it mandatory to make ablution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Taharah* (ritual purity) is not an obligation for making the *adhan* (call to prayer), but as with any act of worship it is recommended.

Ref: http://islamqa.com/en/ref/20411